# Hadith: There is a way to cleanse everything

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

Is the following hadith (I guess it could be slightly in different in translation) present in sahih hadith books?

> There is a way to cleanse everything and the way to cleanse the heart
>   is through dhkir of Allah.